# NuxtJs/axios api 404 not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

Using `nuxt` and for http request `axios`, here is config:

**nuxt.config.js**

```
  axios: {
    proxy: true,
    https: true,
    prefix: '/api'
  }
```

**form.vue**

```
this.$axios.$post('/mail', {
...
}
```

After submit the form, request url is:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/mail
```

But:

> POST http://localhost:3000/api/mail 404 (Not
>   Found)

In my project:

```
/api
- index.js
- /routes
    -- /mail.js
```

**index.js:**

```
const express = require('express')
var mail = require('./routes/mail.js')
```

**mail.js**

```
var router = express.Router()
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var mailInfo = req.body
  var mailDetails = getMailDetails(mailInfo.type, mailInfo.body)
  var mailOptions = {
    priority: 'high',
    from: process.env.SENDGRID_FROM || 'contact@test.com',
    to: mailInfo.to || mailDetails.to,
    subject: mailDetails.subject,
    html: mailDetails.msg
  }
  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error)
      res.status(404).json(error)
    } else {
      // console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
      res.status(200).json({
        message: 'email sent successfully'
      })
    }
  })
})
module.exports = router
```

Any idea?
    ..

Comment: I'm amazed you get 404, considering your not listening anywhere, whats in `./routes/mail.js`? because the code in index.js has no routes setup, and does not do alot

Comment: Exactly, you did not set up the server that listens to your axios request. Your client code seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify the address of the server to which you want to access as proxy?

```
// nuxt.config.js

proxy: {
  'prefix': 'url'
}
```

Comment: Show proxy settings or nuxt.config.js settings.